# Having trouble checking if an array has data or is empty in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array in my state I set my state default value to an empty array `[]`. After an API request loads I need to use loader until data is ready. So U use condition like:

```
(if array length  === 0  loader will show otherwise data will show)
```

but when the API returns empty data I want to show no data available.

What is best way to do that?

My code is below - how can I check the condition if the API returns an empty result?

```
this.state.offer.length == 0 ?  <Loader /> : <OfferList />
```

Comment: When you get the API result you should check if it's length is 0, then have a flag in state and set that like `if responseFromAPI.length==0 this.setState({emptyAPIResponse: true})`, then use that for conditional rendering

Comment: Could you provide your `render` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest would be to have the default be `undefined` rather than an empty array. Then in your render check:

- `undefined` means its loading
- empty array means no data, so show message
- non-empty array you can shown data

`{!this.state.offer ? <Loader /> : this.state.offer.length ?  <OfferList /> : <span>No data available</span>}`

Comment: That's how to do it. Thanks for this smart solution!

Comment: yes you are right but is it possible to set default state undefined in Redux?

Comment: this is react state, if this was redux state it would be passed in via props

Comment: @NarayananS If you were to do this via redux and props its still doable even with redux's restrictions, except instead of `undefined` as your reducer's default, you would use `null`, as this is an acceptable return value from reducer. The logic being it being that `undefined ` is disallowed because it could just be no state passed at all to the reducer arg, while `null` is an explicit value that has been set. I use this pattern for exactly this purpose and works a treat

Answer (score 2):

Best approach would be to use the ternary operation. First initialize offer to be `undefined` and you API returns an empty array if there is no data. Next use below expression in render method().

`{this.state.offer === undefined ?  <Loader /> : this.state.offer.length > 0 ? <OfferList /> : "No data Available"}`

Comment: indeed this is the best approach this answer worth more than the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not show or hide the loader on the basis of the size of your array it should depend on your AJAX call.

Simply you can put a variable in your state like "isLoading", mark it true on making ajax call and mark it false on response independent of whether it is a success or failure.

`this.state ={
  offer: [],
  isLoading: false
}`

on ajax, call

`this.setState({isLoading:true});`

on the response, call

`this.setState({isLoading:true});`

and you can display

> no data available on the basis of size of array.

Answer (score -1):

Add another property in your `state` denoting processing like below

```
state = {
  offer: [],
  processing: false
}
```

then use this property to `show/hide` your loader.

You can set/unset this property, while you make API call.

Comment: Flags are harmful. If there's any way to compute boolean values this is the right way to go. So have a look @alechill s answer which is quite good.

Comment: Would you try to explain, why flags are harmful?

Comment: In simple words you have now 1 more state variable to handle just for hide/ show.

Comment: That is ok and I guess it is personal preference. But I didn't get why it is harmful.

Comment: Yes of course - sorry for this statement without any explanation :-D I think you are aware of the single responsibility principle. It says that each function should have exactly one functionality and not two or more. Any boolean value that you pass into a class or function can be splitted into two functions or two classes which then have a single resposibility. So each time you use a boolean value check if it's really necessary or if you oversee a huge problem in your whole app architecture which is often the case

Comment: I guess same can be applied to `offer` as well. Let's say a person want to refresh the list, then state need to be set to undefined and that will clear the list and user will not see anything on the page for that period. I will say this is poor user experience.

Comment: So to have a real world example which is based on your approach: Imagine you set "offer" after a successful request, but forget to set processing to false. Then your render wouldn't work as expected. What you expect from setting "offer" is to rerender the component which is not the case. So your render function is dependend on a boolean value which means your function has more than one task and that violates the single responsibility principle. Could you follow me? :-D It's really hard to explain :-D

Comment: Maybe one more addition to make a point: With 2 values you must handle at least 4 different states. With 1 value at least two, in our case 3 (and that's what you are totally right is an issue and not completely solved yet. The undefined is still a problem)

Comment: I totally agree on your points but still setting state isn't a problem as they can be abstracted to methods or via reducers. Anyway, I guess we can end this discussion. :)

Comment: This final comment hits the nail on the head - with a flag in the component, the component is fully tied to the implementation of the request for data, which i'd argue is a side effect that should not belong inside the component at all, as you suggest too. If then we want to refactor to move somewhere more appropriate and the data be supplied by props, then this loading UI with flag has to be reimplemented also, whereas displaying based on the data array simply being present or not will use exact same display logic as when it was in local state